# For each PHP function not working?

Tags: php

I am following along with a video series and the same code as them that I am using doesn't work for some reason. I am getting this error:

**Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/lr/core/functions/general.php on line 8**

My general.php page is:

```
<?php
function sanitize($data)    {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

function output_errors($errors) {
    $output = array();
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error, ', ';
    }
}
```

And my login.php page is:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false)    {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password']; 

if (empty($username) === true|| empty($password) === true)  {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and/or password.';
} else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
} else if (user_active($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account! Check your email.'; 
} else {

    $login = login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors = 'That username/password combination is incorrect.';
    } else{
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        ?>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.php">
        <?php
        exit();
    }   
}
}else {
$errors[] = 'No data received';
}

include 'includes/overall/overall_header.php';
output_errors($errors);
include 'includes/overall/overall_footer.php';
?>
```

The video episode is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XvbXxqJ4xQ&list=ECE134D877783367C7 but i am not getting the same result. Thank you.

Comment: Also if you are wondering what the <meta> tag is for, it is because header('Location') wasnt working, so i quick fixed it and it works fine.

Comment: Why did you tag java in this?

Comment: Why not `return implode(', ', $errors);`? instead of the `foreach`?

Comment: I found the error. On line 18 of login.php the code was "error = 'That username/password combination is incorrect.'" not "error[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect.'"

Comment: Would return implode do the same thing. Like whats the dif?

Comment: You don't need a `foreach` on a numerically indexed array; it's just *gauche*. You should also not bury output by putting `echo`'s in functions that work like that. `echo output_errors($errors);` and a sanity check for array and or string should be sufficient. `implode` is the opposite of `explode`.

Comment: @KyelJmD I'm not sure I might have accidentally typed it. Sorry.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks, I will have to try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update general.php with some quick checks before processing in `foreach()`. `foreach()` is expecting an array to be passed, the error you're seeing indicates it is a non-array or empty-member array.

The `is_array()` function verifies that $errors is in fact an array, `count()` comparison makes sure there is at least one array member to loop through using `foreach()`.

```
<?php
function sanitize($data)    {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

function output_errors($errors) {
    $output = array();
    if ( is_array( $errors) && count( $errors ) > 0 ){
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo $error, ', ';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this result in the same output?

Comment: Yes, precisely the same. The problem is somewhere output_errors() is being called without an array being passed in. When output_errors() then tries to foreach() through the array, it can't, because it is not an array (or is empty).

Comment: I found the error. On line 18 of login.php the code was "error = 'That username/password combination is incorrect.'" not "error[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect.'"

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the `$errors` variable properly above your branch:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

$errors = array(); // <-- added

if (empty($_POST) === false)    {
```

Without this, `$errors` is implicitly passed as `null` to your function (and a notice is raised) and `null` is obviously not an array.

Comment: I believe that is in another document. Let me check.